# Laravel 5.2 Ajax internal server error 500

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 with ajax but I have internal server error 500 when I click on the link for example.

Here my code . . .

Blade file:

```
<a class="delete" href="#" data-userid="{{ $user->id }}">X</a>
```

Js file:

```
var userId = 0;
$('.delete').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
userId = event.target.dataset['userid'];

$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url: 'users/delete',
    data: {userId: userId, _token: token}
}).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
    });
    console.log(userId);
});
```

Route file:

```
Route::post('users/delete', 'HomeController@delete');
```

HomeController file:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    $user = POST::find($request['userId']);
    $user->delete();
    return response();
}
```

Js file works good out of laravel . . .
Of course I have database with users table, and connection with database.
I'm working locally and using windows 10.

This is error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the `500` error referring to? Have you checked your logs?

Comment: Yes I have checked, this is here

Comment: [2016-04-30 21:35:42] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\POST' not found' in C:\project-user\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php:47

Comment: POST::find ?? Did you mean User::find?

Comment: I have changed to User::find , I still have same error but the user deleted, It's almost work

Comment: Ok, what is the POST here? a model? have you included it in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try using request Method as DELETE rather than a POST ?

It may fix your error. Here. Below check example for delete.

http://www.sitepoint.com/crud-create-read-update-delete-laravel-app/

Answer (score 0):

> [2016-04-30 21:35:42] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\POST' not found' in C:\project-user\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php:47

looks like you didn't imported POST with `use` keyword or you used wrong class (not `POST`)

Answer (score 0):

use this
 (check if POST is the right name for ur model in App folder)

```
  $user = \POST::findOrfail($request->input('userId');
  $user->delete();
  return response()->json('Success');
```

in js

```
success: function(response){
 console.log(response);
}
```